# Masters research with 3 months left, poor choice of supervisor and topic, is poor thesis with rehashed results be accepted?

Tags: thesis, advisor, masters

From India. I chose a poor supervisor who seduced me with potential progress. I soon realized that the topic was bland, highly theoretical, and only practical in high-end labs. All you can do is simulations in open source software that are just running first order approximations about the model.

I soon grew bored. The supervisor can't even explain stuff. He even "gaslights" us (3 of us are suffering individually) saying how cooperative he is. I almost lost control several times. Three of us agree that he has very poor communication skills. He even threatened one of us saying he will not accept his work. When asked a doubt he finds some paper in 5 minutes by Googling and asks us to read it. He doesn't read the work I sent to him properly.

Until now I have rehashed results from some existing literature and have convinced my evaluation panel. They are satisfied because of my good presentation skill alone and due to the fact the topic is very new. But that was all I did until last semester. I have three more months left. I don't know what to do.

I did try to change the topic and supervisor. I even had a professor who thinks highly of me, someone whose interests I align with ready to take me, but the department head said I can't change topics midway.

I have a dream job at a billion dollar company for a role that aligns with my interest coming up in 4 months. One I only dreamed of when I was a school kid. Now I am afraid that I will lose it.

Will my masters work be accepted in its current state?

I did not bring any novelty, all I did was read about things and present it, and write some code that I obtained from various sources (cited of course). One thing about my topic is even accepted papers in journals are full of grave dangerous assumptions, as a matter of fact, a paper with these rehashed existing results I sent to an international conference exclusively on this topic was accepted!

Comment: There are too many variables, mostly unknown, to make a good answer. It depends a lot on the standards for graduation at your place. You might be fine. Or not. A lot might depend on the advisor's judgement and standards.

Comment: Strictly spoken, the requirement of originality typically only applies to PhDs. So, an MSc demonstrates your capability of doing research, understanding and applying academic-level methods etc., but not actually finding new things. In other words, if you do the rest correctly, it is not critical that your results are not novel, as long as the methodology is soundly scientific (and that includes appropriate use of literature). I suggest you abandon the "jerk" thinking about people who may or may not have other constraints imposed on their decision, we don't know. Try your best and good luck.

Comment: @CaptainEmacs and Buffy Please do not use comments to answer the question!

Comment: Sorry to hear of your difficulties, but this is a Q&A site. The only Q here is “will they accept my work,” and only “they” can answer that.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni In principle I agree with your point. However, as the question was formulated, my comment was not strictly an answer to the question, so I did not promote it to answer, despite considering this.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni Strictly speaking I think you're right, though Buffy's comment mostly explains our too individualized close reason. However I don't think the community wants moderators to be that strict with comment deletion on closed questions that can't be answered.

Comment: @CaptainEmacs Ideally in this situation you might link to another Q&A here that focuses on originality expectations in masters theses.